# heroku showing first user at last page in RailsTutorials chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am following RubyonRails Tutorialsby Hartl's (chapter 9)..

the list of all users on my local machine is showing as according to their user id.

**As "AKS"(user name is having id = 1 and is also an admin to this page)is displaying at top of the list but the same thing after uploading at Herokuapp, list is displaying differently**.

The first user is present at the Last page, however the second user and onwards are still showing on First Page.
Can anyone please suggest me what shall i do to display list properly at Herokuapp.com
I have attached the images of list showing at localhost and at heroku.

**First image is the list showing at Local machine and the second one is the list showing at heroku**
[image: This is the list Showing on localhost:3000]

[image: This is the list showing at Herokuapp.com]

**Content of users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]

before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
  #@users = User.all
   @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end


def new
    @user = User.new
  end


def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to sample app"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
  end



  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end


    # below code for signed_in_user can also be written as
    #def signed_in_user
     # redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    #end

     # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

   def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

   def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**Content of index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h2>All users</h2>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= render @users %>              <!--"render user" or "render @user" in Rails will search for _user.html.erb file-->

  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

tell me if more codes needed to be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in You each block You are rendering ALL users per one user.  Probably You would want to change this:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= render @users %>
  <% end %>
```

to this:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= render user%>
  <% end %>
```

Secondly, whenever You are having ordering issues checkout what SQL queries are executed on each page (adjust Your log level to `:debug` on Heroku to see those). It's considered a bad practice to rely on auto ordering and it's always better to explicitly specify ordering column like this:

```
@users = User.order(:id).paginate(page: params[:page]) # default order always is ASC
```

Comment: can you please tell me to set log level to :debug on heroku.

Comment: You can set log level in Your environment file, don't forget to check which environment is Your Heroku app using, by default it's production. So if You haven't touched Heroku config, You probably want to adjust production.rb

By writing `render @users`, You pass the whole array to render method. But obviously You want to pass a SINGLE user, because You are already iterating through the list. I checked the tutorial and actually the author is doing everything right, Your code is wrong: 
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-index_view_first_refactoring

Comment: ohh ok ok now i got it..yes you are right .. "render @users" doesn't need an iteration. sorry thats my mistake..thanks a lot friend :)